# SQL : SubQuery with Group By

Tags: subquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL : How can I use sub query in a query with group by section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583767/sql-how-can-i-use-sub-query-in-a-query-with-group-by-section)

Some one help me please . SQL Server cant recognize t1.sen in subquery . Error message : The multi-part identifier "t1.sen" could not be bound.

```
select
    t1.sen,
    sum(t1.d_rooz)as d1,
    sum(t1.d_shab)as d2,
    sum(t1.d_rooz+t1.d_shab) as d_sum,
    Round((sum((1000*(t1.d_rooz+t1.d_shab))/(9500-tc.c))),1) as SSS
from
    tbl_talafat_dan t1, (
       select sum(t2.t_shab+t2.t_rooz) as c
       from tbl_talafat_dan t2
       where FCode=81 AND DCode=1 AND t2.sen<=t1.sen
    ) as tc
where
    FCode = 81
    AND DCode = 1
group by
    t1.sen
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a syntax issue here after t1:

```
from
    tbl_talafat_dan t1, (
       select sum(t2.t_shab+t2.t_rooz) as c
       from tbl_talafat_dan t2
       where FCode=81 AND DCode=1 AND t2.sen<=t1.sen
    ) as tc
```

It's trying to figure out what's the table to select from. You need to use either t1 or tc and join after that appropriately. Hope this helps.